# Reading multiple strings from file seperated with space, using fscanf

Tags: c

So i want to read some strings from a text file that are seperated with spaces. The code i have been using is this:

```
int main() {
  char name[9];
  char surname[20];
  char phone[10];
  int code, nscan;
  char termch;
  FILE* infile;

 infile = fopen("I4F6.txt", "r");
if (infile == NULL)
 printf("Error reading text file\n");


 while (TRUE){

nscan= fscanf(infile, "%[^ ] %[^ ] %[^ ] %d%c",
                         name, surname, phone, &code, &termch);


 printf("%s %s %s %d\n", name ,surname, phone, code);


  if (nscan == EOF)
    break;
  if (nscan != 5 || termch != '\n')
    printf("Error line\n");
  }   
   return 0;
}
```

An the text file goes like this, with the name first, then the surname, a phone number that needs to be saved as string and a code.

```
nikos dimitriou 6911111112 1
maya satratzemi 6933333332 20
marios nikolaou 6910001112 15
maria giannou 6914441112 1
dimitra totsika 6911555111 14
giannis pappas 6911111222 16
nikos ploskas 6911111662 20
```

But the result i get from this printf is this:

```
nikos  6911111112 1

maya  6933333332 20

marios  6910001112 15

maria  6914441112 1

dimitra  6911555111 14

giannis  6911111222 16

nikos  6911111662 20

Error line
nikos  6911111662 20
```

So as you can see it skips all the surnames and produces an error line.

So what should I do to read and store every value seperated with space from the text file into a variable?

Thanks for your time

Comment: @MohitJain So you're example works fine and thank you for that :)) But with what should i replace "if (termch =! '\n')" now that the termch is int?

Comment: What happens if you skip the spaces in fscanf?

Comment: `int main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: The approach of using `"%[^ ] %[^ ] %[^ ] %d%c"` will get fooled with input like `"nikos\ndimitriou\n6911111112\n1\n`".  Suggest first using `fgets()` to read the _line_.

Answer (score 0):

OP's key problem is using `char phone[10];` to store `"6911111112"` which needs 11 `char`.  This all leads to undefined behavior with the unlimited `%[^ ]`

> what should I do to read and store every value separated with space from the text file into a variable?

`*scanf()` is difficult to use to detects *lines* and not get fooled with line endings like `"\r\n"`.  Better to read the *line* and then parse it and use width limited fields.

Consider using `%n` (it stores the scan offset) to detect a proper scan.

```
char name[9];
char surname[20];
char phone[10+1];

char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, infile)) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, " %8[^ ] %19[^ ] %10[^ ]%d %n", name, surname, phone, &code, &n);

  // incomplete scan or extra text detected
  if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
    printf("Error line\n");  // do not use name, surname, phone, code
    break;
  }

  printf("%s %s %s %d\n", name, surname, phone, code);
}
```